# PHP push array into existing array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a php file I am using to create a JSON output. You can see my loop in the code below:

```
foreach($objQueueData->event as $event){ 

            $output[] = array(
                "eventID" => (int)$event->trainingEventID,
                "eventTitle" => (string)$event->teTitle,
                "eventDescription" => (string)$event->teDesc,
                "eventSource" => (string)$event->teSource,
                "eventType" => (string)$event->teType,
                "eventMedium" => (string)$event->teMedium,
                "eventRequestor" => (string)$event->creatorFirst . ' ' . $event->creatorLast,
                "eventRequestorNTID" => (string)$event->creatorNTID,
                "eventRequestDate" => (string)$event->teCreated,
                "eventDirector" => (string)$event->teDirector,
                "eventTeammateImpact" => (string)$event->teTeammateImpact,
                "eventCustomerImpact" => (string)$event->teCustomerImpact,
                "eventComplexity" => (string)$event->teComplexity,
                "eventInitiativeID" => (int)$event->intID,
                "eventNeededBy" => (string)$event->teNeededBy
            );
            $impactedRegions = array();
            if(isset($event->regionalImpact->option)){
                foreach ($event->regionalImpact->option as $region) {
                    $impactedRegions[] = $region->impact;
                }
                array_push($output, $impactedRegions);
            }
        }
        // Set the content type to JSON  for jquery to understand
        header('Content-Type: text/json');

        // Print the response to the page
        print json_encode($output);
```

My issue is with the second array `impactedRegions`. This should be a sub array of `output` but it is not working as intended.

I am trying to have it be apart of the `output` array.

Here is what the current JSON output looks like:

```
    [

   {

      "eventID": 25,

      "eventTitle": "Monday",

      "eventDescription": "Testing Monday",

      "eventSource": "OE",

      "eventType": "New Hire",

      "eventMedium": "ILT",

      "eventRequestor": "Carl",

      "eventRequestorNTID": "ch123",

      "eventRequestDate": "Nov 17 2014  4:58PM",

      "eventDirector": "",

      "eventTeammateImpact": "Medium",

      "eventCustomerImpact": "High",

      "eventComplexity": "Low",

      "eventInitiativeID": 1069,

      "eventNeededBy": "2014-11-18"

   },

   [

      {

         "0": "Americas"

      }

   ],
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($event->regionalImpact->option as $region) {
     $output['regions'][] = $region->impact;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is you are using `array_push()` with an associative array.  I believe `array_push` is for pushing values to an `indexed` array.

Trying specifying the key by using `$output['impactedRegions'] = $impactedRegions;` instead.

```
        $impactedRegions = array();
        if(isset($event->regionalImpact->option)){
            foreach ($event->regionalImpact->option as $region) {
                $impactedRegions[] = $region->impact;
            }
            $output['impactedRegions'] = json_encode($impactedRegions);
        }
```

Also, `json_encode($impactedRegions)` will encode the array so it's included as a json object in your original array.

Comment: This is close but it needs to be part of the original array, its currently outside of it.

Comment: Original array?  I though you wanted `$impactedRegions` to be a subArray of `$output`.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe I am miss using the word Sub. This is a standard nested array I am looking for. The main array contains all of that data and then there is a sub array within that record containing an array of the regions it impacts

Comment: Ohh, I see the problem.  I think you may need to json encode the subArray before including it into the original array.

Comment: Still not what I am looking for :/

Comment: Do a `var_dump($output)` at the bottom and see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($objQueueData->event as $key => $event){ 

        $output[$key] = array(
            "eventID" => (int)$event->trainingEventID,
            "eventTitle" => (string)$event->teTitle,
            "eventDescription" => (string)$event->teDesc,
            "eventSource" => (string)$event->teSource,
            "eventType" => (string)$event->teType,
            "eventMedium" => (string)$event->teMedium,
            "eventRequestor" => (string)$event->creatorFirst . ' ' . $event->creatorLast,
            "eventRequestorNTID" => (string)$event->creatorNTID,
            "eventRequestDate" => (string)$event->teCreated,
            "eventDirector" => (string)$event->teDirector,
            "eventTeammateImpact" => (string)$event->teTeammateImpact,
            "eventCustomerImpact" => (string)$event->teCustomerImpact,
            "eventComplexity" => (string)$event->teComplexity,
            "eventInitiativeID" => (int)$event->intID,
            "eventNeededBy" => (string)$event->teNeededBy
        );
        $impactedRegions = array();

        if(isset($event->regionalImpact->option)){

            foreach ($event->regionalImpact->option as $region) {
                $impactedRegions[] = $region->impact;
            }                
        }

        $output[$key]['impactedRegions'] = $impactedRegions;
    }
    // Set the content type to JSON  for jquery to understand
    header('Content-Type: text/json');

    // Print the response to the page
    print json_encode($output);
```